# Function pointer accepting argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[]);
```

What does the above declaration means? Does it mean

**ptr is pointer to a function that accepts an argument which is array of pointers to characters returning integer?**

How to evaluate?

Comment: This was one area of C that the designers got terribly badly wrong!

Comment: True! It becomes hard to evaluate such expressions..

Comment: This is a syntax error.

Comment: Let me [cdecl that for you](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*p%29%28char%28*%29%5B%5D%29)...

Comment: @DyP I donot think so, it compiles fine in VC++ editor..

Comment: @PowerPC Huh, my cdecl must be broken o.O

Comment: @PowerPC I don't think that we can view MSVC as a good guide of what is or is not valid C++

Comment: @KerrekSB You passed something other than what is in the question to cdecl

Comment: The problems with cdecl seem to come from the identifiers `ptr` and `ch`. Use something else instead of `ptr` and leave out `ch`.

Comment: Does cdecl not allow function parameters to be named at all?  This should be a valid declaration of `ptr`, with the identifier `ch` effectively ignored.

Comment: I think that a person that is writing this code is not being reasonable. Please write a program that has a narrative and easy to understand. When you do not do this then testing your software is impossible or difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's rule: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Briefly, you should start from identifier, then parse everything from identifier to the right (it can be `()` - *function* or `[]` *array*), then parse everything from identifier to the left. Parentheses changes this order - you should parse everything in the most inner parentheses first and so on, it works like with arithmetic calculations.

In other words, there is an *order of precedence* (which can be changed by parentheses), from higher to lower:

1) `()` - *function* and `[]` - *array*, from left to right;

2) `*` - *pointer*, *type*, *type modifier*, from right to left.

---

*Your example*

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[])
```

We start from identifier

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[]);  // (1)ptr
      |_|                      
       1
```

Identifier `ptr` is in parentheses, so we parse everything in parenteses first

```
(*ptr)  // (1)ptr
  |_|       
   1
```

There's nothing to the right, so we parse to the left

```
(*ptr)  // (1)ptr is (2)a pointer
 ||_|       
 2 1
```

We finished in parentheses, now we parse to the right of parentheses

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[]);  // (1)ptr is (2)a pointer to (3)function
     ||_| |____________|
     2 1        3
```

So far we ignore function arguments and parse to the left of parentheses

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[]);  // (1)ptr is (2)a pointer to (3)function which returns (4)int
|_| ||_| |____________|
 4  2 1        3
```

In the same way we parse argument of function (I've inserted some spaces for better alignment)

```
char  (* ch )[ ]  // (1)ch is (2)a pointer to (3)array of (4)chars
|___|  | |_| |_|
  4    2  1   3
```

Finally, we have:

**ptr is a pointer to function which returns int and accepts a pointer to array of chars as argument**

Answer (score 4):

ptr is pointer to a function that accepts an **argument which is a pointer** to an array of characters, returning integer.

Comment: how do u evaluate the same?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can you phrase it differently?

Comment: I mean, how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: The way you think about this is as follows. To declare a pointer argument, first omit the star and just declare the type. In your case this is "char ch[]". Which is an array of chars. Then you add the star before the name. But here you have to use parens, because otherwise it would confuse the type ("char" vs "char star"). So, it becomes "char (star ch)[]".

Comment: "array of characters" isn't a valid target type for a pointer though.  You need "array of `N` characters" for some integral `N`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have written, `ptr` is a pointer to a function that returns `int`, and takes as an argument a pointer to an array of `char`.

However, you are not allowed to have a pointer to an array without a bound on the array. So, your variable is incorrectly specified, and will not compile. It seems you want `ptr` to have a type that can accept a pointer to a function that can take any size array. This requires a template construction. For a function argument, it would have the form:

```
template <unsigned N>
int foo (int (*ptr)(char (*)[N])) {
    //...
}
```

Normally, the way to simplify such types is to use `typedef` to represent the complicated parts, so that the variable itself becomes a simple pointer to some type. This is particularly useful when trying to write a function that returns a function pointer.

```
void x (char *s) {}
typedef void xtype (char *);

void (* y_hard ())(char *) { return x; }
xtype * y_easy () { return x; }
```

However, the parameterized nature of the function argument makes that harder to achieve. Assuming C++ 11, you can use the following construct ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17033706/315052)):

```
template <unsigned N>
using ArrayArg = const char [N];

template <unsigned N>
using Function = int (ArrayArg<N> *);

template <unsigned N>
int foo (Function<N> *ptr) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in **GCC**.

Yes `ptr` is a function pointer. It is a pointer to a function returning an integer and accepting a pointer to a character array as argument.

Consider the function fun with the following prototype,

```
int fun(char (*ptr)[]);
```

`fun()` is a function accepting a pointer to a character array as argument.

and the following piece of code compile without any error or warning,

```
int (*ptr)(char (*ch)[]);
ptr=fun;
```

Comment: The question is tagged c++. G++ fails to compile this code. See: http://ideone.com/G7kJpr