# How to use typedef to simplify tempate function argument that is a function pointer

Tags: c++

I would like to simplify `foo` by using a `typedef` to represent the type for the `ptr` argument.

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned N>
int foo (int (*ptr) (const char (*)[N])) {
    char good[N] = "good";
    return ptr(&good);
}

int bar (const char (*x)[5]) {
    std::cout << *x << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    return foo(bar);
}
```

I would like to write `foo()` to be more like this:

```
template <unsigned N>
int foo (FUNCTION_TYPE *ptr) {
    char good[N] = "good";
    return ptr(&good);
}
```

I tried using a traits like helper class, [but that failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033009/array-trait-causes-template-argument-deduction-failure). *Is there a proper way to create a* `typedef` *for* `FUNCTION_TYPE`*?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you can get the rough equivalent of a template typedef by using the `using` keyword. This still allows `N` to be deduced from the argument:

```
template <unsigned N>
using fooP = int (*) (const char (*)[N]);

template <unsigned N>
int foo (fooP<N> ptr) {
  return ptr(0);
}

int bar(const char (*p)[2]) {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  return foo(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a default template argument:

```
template <unsigned N, typename T = int (*) (const char (*)[N])>
int foo (T ptr);
```

[Here is a compiling demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dcd487f62ff52260b99df803980172dc-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f)

Another option is to use `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int foo(std::function<int(std::string)>& ptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's probably a bad use case for default template arguments. It makes `int bar(int (const char(*)[3])); foo<2>(bar);` compile without any issues.

Comment: @hvd [Um..no it doesn't...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8385c44c894eee4c747bd070f35a136e-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f)

Comment: Your compiling demo using `foo<5>(bar)`. I want template argument deduction to work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Try simply `return 0;` in `foo`. It compiles or doesn't depending on whether the instantiation succeeds. In your example, it fails, but in general, it could very well succeed.

Comment: @jxh You won't get type deduction with this, but why not use `std::function<int(std::string)>` instead?

Comment: I want foo() to pass a pointer to the right array size to the passed in function. See the updated post. Consider the N parameter and the body of foo() to be immutable.

Comment: @jxh Then I wouldn't know how to do this. See the other answers, they seem to have got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just make it template

```
template<unsigned N, typename Func) 
int foo(Func func){ return func("good"); }

int bar(const std::string& str){ return str == "good"; }

int main(){    const int r = foo(bar); }
```

That way not only are you not limited to passing regular functions but you can also pass in [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: I am aware of this, but I want `foo()` to pass a pointer to the right array size to the passed in function. See the updated post. Consider the `N` parameter and the body of `foo()` to be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

So your basic problem is that dependent types are not inferred in a function call.

Assuming you want to deduce the value `N` while doing away with that mess, what you need is the ability to map from the function type to the value `N`.

```
template<typename Func>
struct get_N {};
template<unsigned int N>
struct get_N< int( const char(*)[N] ) > {
  typedef std::integral_constant< unsigned int, N > type;
};
template<typename Func>
using getN = typename get_N<Func>::type;
```

once you have this, you can use it in the `template` type arguments:

```
template <typename Func, typename Nt = getN<Func>>
int foo (Func* ptr) {
  constexpr N = Nt::value;
  return ptr(&"good");
}
```

and we have access to the `N` within `foo`, and the only things (barring some fancy footwork) that can match `foo` are things that `get_N` understands (via SFINAE).

Comment: This is a nifty workaround. I believe `integral_constant` is C++11. But some version of your solution should be portable to C++-03, right?

Comment: Yes.  Integral constant is a really simple one, it just makes `value` equal to the value passed in (it also does typing, but you can just do an `enum` or whatever).